# KineticJS change color of text onclick

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am working on KineticJS(Latest version) and i have issue regarding change text color which drawn by drawFunc() shape object.

1)Here is the code of Shpae Object.

```
var sampleText = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x:380,
    y:700,
    drawFunc: function(context) {
    context.beginPath();          
       var x = 0;
       var y = 0;
       var text = 'Sample Text';
       context.setAttr("font", '15pt Calibri');
       context.setAttr('fillStyle','black');          
       context.fillText(text, x, y)
       context.closePath();
       // KineticJS specific context method
       context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    },  
    id:"sampleText"
});
```

2)I want to change color of "sample text" on click event which is written using core html5 code (context object).

```
colorTabViews.on('click', function (e) {
    sampleText.sceneFunc(function(context) {
        context.beginPath();
        //how can i get text which already displayed in shape object("Sample text")?
        //or to change color of "sample text"
        context.setAttr('fillStyle','green');

        context.closePath();
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    });
    verticalText.draw();
});
```

But issue is ,it removes whole text nothing displayed instead of just changing "sample text" color.

Please advice either get text filled by context.fillText() function or alternate way that i can change text color on particular event.

Thanks for your time and consideration in advance.
-Naitik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To programatically change fillStyle inside a Kinetic.Shape**

Attach a fill property to your shape object and reference your fill property inside the Kinetic.Shape:

```
var sampleText = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x:10,
    y:15,
    sceneFunc: function(context) {
      context.beginPath();          
      var x = 0;
       var y = 0;
       var text = 'Sample Text';
       context.setAttr("font", '15pt Calibri');
       context.setAttr('fillStyle',this.myFillStyle);          
       context.fillText(text, x, y)
       context.closePath();
       // KineticJS specific context method
       context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    },  
    id:"sampleText",
    fill:"blue"
});

// add a property to sampleText that's used in its sceneFunc
sampleText.myFillStyle="black";
```

Then you can change that fill property in your click handler:

```
colorTabViews.on('click', function (e) {
    sampleText.myFillStyle="red";
    verticalText.draw();
});
```